# Right syntax of file.Exists(path)

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my website folder has a folder: `Lecturer`, in `Lecturer` folder has many childrens folder: `lecturer1, lecturer2, lecturer3....`, the name of child folder is the name of user login (`username`)

```
     string username = Session["user"].ToString();
     string path = this.Server.MapPath("~/Lecturer/");
     string targetPath = path + username +"\\profile.xml";

      bool isExists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(targetPath);

       if(isExists)
        {
             //do something...
        }
```

It still has a file: `profile.xml` in each `lecturer(n)` folder, but the `isExists= false`.

Try to debug:

```
username: lecturer1 
path: "D:\\C#Projects\\website\\Lecturer\\"
targetPath: "D:\\C#Projects\\website\\Lecturer\\lecturer1\\profile.xml"
```

but `isExists: false.`

Help??? Is there any mistake in my code above???

Comment: Did you try the path without the trailing slash?  Also, why are you checking if a directory exists on a file?  It won't exist if it is not a directory

Comment: Use [`Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991142.aspx) instead of  string concatenation to build paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`targetPath` is a `File` not a Directory, so use `File.Exists` instead of `Directory.Exists`

```
bool isExists = System.IO.File.Exists(targetPath);
```

Comment: oh thank you, poor me, cannot believe that I don't realize that. Thank again ^^